# Implement Circular Queue using Array

Tags: c

I have try to make an Circular queue using array for a token to prioritize the process of reading function. What i have use until now is this code to write an read in array:

```
#define QUEUE_ELEMENTS 5
#define QUEUE_SIZE (QUEUE_ELEMENTS + 1)
int Queue[QUEUE_SIZE];
int QueueIn, QueueOut;

int QueuePut(uint8 new_token)
{
    if(QueueIn == (( QueueOut - 1 + QUEUE_SIZE) % QUEUE_SIZE))
    {
        return -1; /* Queue Full*/
    }
    Queue[QueueIn] = new_token;
    QueueIn = (QueueIn + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
    return 0; // No errors
}

int QueueGet(uint8 *old_token)
{
    if(QueueIn == QueueOut)
    {
        return -1; /* Queue Empty - nothing to get*/
    }
    *old_token = Queue[QueueOut];
    QueueOut = (QueueOut + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
    return 0; // No errors
}
```

What i need is an index of array cell where i write my value to return which I want to use for reading. To set the index to 2 an read from cell with index 2 and after update the values in cell number 2 with new values.
How can i do that?
Here is a interaction diagram for what i need to do that queue array with token. For that method get token i need to get the index of array where i put my copy in the array but I think the index in my code is **QueueIN**.
[only the critical part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke24x.jpg)

Comment: can you give an example, you description is hard to understand?

Comment: Do you simply want a stack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) ?

Comment: What i need is something like in this example [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/8-List/array-queue2.html)

Comment: awful to understand what the problem is here :D

Comment: can you elaborate more about your wish to implement ?  @AdrianMoldovan